# CSS Drop Down - Disappearing on hover

Tags: html, css

I know this will be a simple fix for all the CSS pros out there but I am fed up with it at the moment and anything I try won't solve it.

When you hover over certain nav items there will be a drop down. I need that little white gap between the drop down and the

item but it disappears as soon as i try to go down. Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a gap between the "GM Parts" button and the dropdown menu. You hover over the button then menu shows up. Then you try to drag your mouse to the menu, but while you are doing this you hover over the gap - that's where "GM Parts" looses :hover state and the menu hides. You need to make sure that there's no gap between "GM Parts" and the menu.